# What is a reason of warning: Autowired annotation is not supported on static fields

Tags: java, spring, autowired

As well as I know, it is not possible to use `@Autowired` annotation for `static` fields using `Spring`. When I run my `JBoss` server, everything works well but I can see few warnings:

```
Autowired annotation is not supported on static fields: private static ...
```

I do not use this annotation really often (in this project I have not used it yet) but maybe some of my colleagues found it more useful.

So, I took one of this warnings:

```
Autowired annotation is not supported on static fields: private static java.lang.String com.my.package.MyClass.myVariable
```

I opened this class and inside is:

```
@Value("${params.myvariable}")
private static String myVariable;
    // getter
    // setter
```

I opened `config.xml`:

```
<bean id="myid" class="com.my.package.MyClass">
    <property name="myVariable" value="${params.myvariable}" />
</bean>
```

As a last thing, I searched in `Eclipse` of `Autowired` strings in my project. Size of the result set was **0**.

So my question is, what is a reason of warning:

```
Autowired annotation is not supported on static fields
```

in this case?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This

```
<bean id="myid" class="com.my.package.MyClass">
    <property name="myVariable" value="${params.myvariable}" />
</bean>
```

means that you have a class `MyClass` such as

```
class MyClass {
    ...
    public void setMyVariable(String value) {
        ...
    }
}
```

With what you describe, the `...` can be replaced with your `static` field

```
private static String myVariable;
// in setter method
myVariable = value;
```

This is a workaround to autowire a `static` field, which normally cannot be done. Spring works on beans (instances), not on classes.